useEffect e localStorage não estao armazenando os dados inseridos quando a pagina é atualizada
quando atualizo a pagina as informaçoes inseridas nao retornam! e sim é uma array e verifiquei inumeras vezes o codigo e esta exatamente identico ao do curso segue abaixo ! no caso estou usando o localStorage com o useEffect e quando atualizo os dados inseridos nao retornam.
e um codigo simples de uma anotador de tarefas, as tarefas são inseridas em um input e depois amarzenadas na array setTarefas e mostras na lista no fim da pagina e no código
no caso quando atualizo ao inves de mostra oque ja foi inserido usando o localStorage quando atualizo some oque foi inserido
segue abaixo o codigo
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [tarefas, setTarefas] = useState([
'Pagar a conta de luz',
'Estudar React JS'
]);
useEffect(()=>{
const tarefasStorage = localStorage.getItem('@tarefa');
if(tarefasStorage){
  setTarefas(JSON.parse(tarefasStorage))
}

}, []);
useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.setItem('@tarefa', JSON.stringify(tarefas))
},[tarefas]);
function handleRegister(e){
e.preventDefault();

setTarefas([...tarefas, input]);
setInput('');

}
return (

Cadastro de usuário
  <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
      <label>Nome da tarefa:</label><br/>
      <input 
      placeholder="Digite uma tarefa"
      value={input}
      onChange={ (e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      /> <br/>

      <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
  
  </form>

  <br></br>   

  <ul>
    {tarefas.map( tarefa =>(
      <li key={tarefa}>{tarefa}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>

</div>

);
}
export default App;

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram postadas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
